# How to specify which axes to plot in a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am new to GUI. But I have two axes in GUIDE GUI and wish to specify the one to plot a figure, but I can't find handles.axe1 anywhere. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Need more information, is this a script, function, GUIDE GUI, programmatic GUI, something else? Please provide some sample code.

Comment: @excaza Yes, it is a GUIDE GUI. I decided not to put the code up here simply bc it is bulky and has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you built your GUI with GUIDE you can easily access the `Tag` property of each axes in the property inspector.

Once you know the tag of each axes, you can choose where to plot stuff using the first argument of `plot`:

```
plot(TagofAxes,x,y)
```

or using `imshow`, using the `Parent` property:

```
imshow(YourImage,'Parent',TagofAxes)
```

and so on.